# Making http requests from a mobile device using an angular web client

Tags: angular

I'm writing a web application that will mostly be used by mobile devices in their web browsers. Part of the application will be sending the users current lat and long from their device or, estimated lat and long from ip address. When the user presses send, in the angular application I am making a http get request to an api that will generate lat and long information from the IP and then subsequently in that promise, I am sending that information through a post request to a backend.

The problem is that on desktop browsers, the application works as intended. On mobile, it seems that the http request isn't being executed, however I am sure that the button is being pressed by using `window.alert()` to debug.

Please take a look at the code and let me know what you guys think..

I've tried standard debugging, but it seems that I can't find a previously asked question that satisfies the question.

home.component.ts

```
  submitForm(){
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      })
    }
    this.http.get('http://ip-api.com/json').subscribe(response=>{
      this.http.post("apiendpoint", response, httpOptions).subscribe(res=>{
        console.log(res)
      })
    })
  }
```

home.component.html

```
    <div class="col">
      <input
        id="submitButton"
        (click)="submitForm()"
        class="btn btn-block btn-success mb-2"
        value="Submit"
      />
    </div>
```

I expect the get request to execute and then have the response posted to the api backend. All that is happening is the user is clicking the button.

Comment: You need to debug on a real device to see the problem. Attach the device to a machine and do remote debugging using Chrome and check the network tab. See what exactly is happening are you making the request or not.

Comment: There is a good chance your server and/or 'http://ip-api.com/json' is either inaccessible from your mobile device or the requests are being blocked by CORS. You must debug as Ahmad has stated or go the long way and throw in error callbacks to your subscribes and display the error messages in some fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I had identical error - Angular PWA works pretty on all devices but mobile chrome. Except that i use keycloak. If you use keycloak or other SSO-solution, may be it's your case to.

No request to backend in console at all. But later i noticed that it reproduced when user is logged in only.

In my case problem was in keycloak. Keycloak adapter intercept all requests to add borrow to each request to back by default. If adapter can't get token, interceptor return empty subscription.

And chrome compress some data to reduce traffic by default and so works as proxy. So i add Cross Origin wildcard "*" to keycloak realm. It solve my problem (but weak security : ).